# What is the reason for this `Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[number]` TypeScript error?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
interface Fn {
  (data: Data): void
}

interface Data<Value = any, Deps extends any[] = [...any]> {
  value: Value
  list: Deps
}

function fn(data: Data<string, [number]>): void {
  console.log(data)
}

const foo: Fn[] = [fn]
console.log(foo)
```

When [tested against the TypeScript Compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGImQbwFDL8gCgBM4w4AuZAEVLgEpKA3Ae2COwF9ttRJZEUNMgB4AanAA2AVxQBeZHBABPADTUIABwDOyCAA9IIIjsVKA2gF1k8swDp7piwD4suZI0kzK46RDcTgLTBKKk0tTm4YKRAEMGBmDBgQYloQ2mEgqFAAczUzECkAWwAjaGcGd1YiV3xkBAStZgkIWwlmbJSyOgjsepAg5BhmZkp0S2tkMySLXoamlraOoeZuoA) this code throws an error because `Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[number]'`.

My intuition is that the defined `fn` is being assigned to the generic `Data` value, but the error states that the assignment goes in the other direction. Is this a bug or limitation with the TypeScript compiler? Or how should I think about this to have a better intuition?

Comment: I'm aware of the distinction @AluanHaddad. The point is that as far as I'm concerned `fn` fits the `Fn` interface because `[number]` can be assigned to `any[]`. The error is that `any[]` cannot be assigned to `[number]` ... while that's obviously true, why is the assignment in that direction?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. My mistake.

Comment: @alecmce aren't you trying to do the reverse here though? You're not passing a number into an any, you're trying to pass an any into a number.

Comment: @Andrew, no. I think you've got the wrong end of the stick here. Please take a look at the link in the question. `Deps` is an array of type `any[]`. The `fn` expression uses a tuple `[number]`, which is not `number[]`, but an array of number with exactly 1 value. As such, `[number]` is a sub-type of `any[]`.  I'm trying to pass a more specific type into a more general case.

Comment: @alecmce no, you have it backwards,and thats why you asked this question. You are trying to assert a type is more specific than it was defined. You are trying to pass a value defined as typed `any[]` into a function asserting it is `[number]` you are asserting something more specific in the function signature than yiu did in the type you are intending to pass, thus any[] is going into [number] which is invalid and will not compile.

Comment: FWIW, yes, I was dumb, twice. It's not the first time. Belatedly, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vastly simplified example of the same problem:

```
type FruitSmasher = (fruit: 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pear') => void
const appleSmasher: FruitSmasher = (apple: 'apple') => undefined
// Type '"apple" | "orange" | "pear"' is not assignable to type '"apple"'.

appleSmasher('orange') // this is bad.
```

`appleSmasher` is not assignable to type `FruitSmasher` because fruit smasher may smash any fruit, but `appleSmasher` only knows how to smash apples. So you *cannot* treat `appleSmasher` like a `FruitSmasher`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAMoFsCGBnAFhOKAXigAoAzRFALigHJMwwAbCOqAH3oHs5MA7AOZtO9SJjh0AlMQB8UAG7ckAEwCwAKADG3ftmBRGLCBhz44teMjRY8BYmSOtaDJq2lyoCfiojkk-BDqGppOJrbmpHS8AsIeAPTxUMC4SNhQaVAARpgqAHRAA)

---

It's backwards to your intuition here because `Fn` here needs to be callable with `any[]` as the `Deps`. That means `[123]`, or `['asd', 123]` or `[]` all need to be allowed as the `Deps` in order to be considered the same type as `Fn`.

However, `fn` actually requires `Deps` be `[number]`, which means that `any[]` isn't going to going to work.

So according to the type of `Fn`. This should be valid:

```
function fn(data: Data<string, [number]>): void {
  console.log(data.list[0].toString()) // this will crash
}

const foo: Fn[] = [fn] // ignore this very valid type error for now

// Valid for type `Fn`, catastrophic for function `fn`.
foo[0]({ value: 123, list: [] })
```

However `fn`'s `Deps` are now unsatisfied. `data.list[0]` would return `undefined`, then would crash on `.toString()`.

So yes `[number]` is assignable to `any[]`. But when the argument to a function is declared as `any[]`, then anything *more* specific than that will break that since that function can't be guaranteed the type that it requires.

Comment: I see, so it's contravariance. Humpf. OK. I guess what confused me is the errror:

```
Type '(data: Data<string, [number]>) => void' is not assignable to type 'Fn'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'Data<any, any[]>' is not assignable to type 'Data<string, [number]>'.
      Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[number]'.
        Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

which switches up the direction of assignment on the last line, which looks like an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's going on. You declare your interface for the `Data` type, saying that the second value of the type is an array that can have any type:

```
interface Data<Value = any, Deps extends any[] = [...any]> {
  value: Value
  list: Deps
}
```

Then you go to use that Data type but say that the second value will be an array of numbers:

```
function fn(data: Data<string, [number]>): void {
  console.log(data)
}
```

So the type says the array can be anything, but the function declaration says the `Data` type guarantees the array will only be numbers, because you are passing an object that conforms to the `Data` interface into something that cannot accept some of the possible forms of that interface.

Remember that typescript really only functions in the IDE and compiler. It ends up being built into JavaScript, an interpreted language with no data types. This means that the function `fn` will actually not throw an error if  you try to pass it an object that has strings in the array once it gets compiled, so the IDE and compiler need to flag it and refuse to accept the structural issue.